# My button on website looks different on Android than on it does on PC. How to change this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My button on website looks different on Android than on it does on PC. How to change this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```html
<div class="plan">
<div class="plan-header">
<a href="" target="_blank" button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-xs  btn-shadow btn-rounded">..</a>
</br></br>
<img src="" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt=""> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as `</br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change specific stylings for specific screen sizes in css with the @media rule. In this case we need to apply rules for the css if the screen has a small size (for maximum of 600px)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>[title]</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <style>
        button {
            border-radius: none;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            button {
                border-radius: 10px;
                height: 20px;
            }
        }

        </style>

        <button>Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: working like a charm, thanks You Sir, You are amazing, really :)

Comment: On chrome (on android) the buttons are rectangular all the time, only in firefox the buttons are rounded, why?

Comment: have you tried writing !important after each css line?  
example:`border-radius: 10px !important`  
  
Or have you tried looking at the css-properties of the button with chrome-debugger to see if it gets overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

Seems btn-light class is conflicting 
try adding this css style to href

> border-color: transparent;